# Extract the contents of a div using Flash AS3

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-3

I have a SFW embedded in a PHP page. There is also a div on the page with `id="target"`.

I want to access the content of that div (ie: the characters inside it) and hold them as a `String` variable in AS3. How can I do this?

**My attempt so far**

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
var myDivContent = ExternalInterface.call("function(){ return document.GetElementById('target');}");
var myDivContent2:String = myDivContent.toString();
test_vars.text = myDivContent2; //Dynamic text output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there :

```
var res : String = ExternalInterface.call("function(){return document.getElementById('target').outerHTML}");
```

If you only want the content of your `target`, use `innerHTML` instead of `outerHTML`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can define a function in the `ExternalInterface.call()` method. You have to call a function by name which already exists in the JavaScript.

So I'd create some JavaScript code like this:

```
function getTargetContent()
{
    return document.getElementById('target').innerHTML;
}
```

And then in your Flash,

```
var myDivContent = ExternalInterface.call("getTargetContent");
```

Note that `document.getElementById('target')` only returns the reference to that div, not the contents within. So if you don't return `.innerHTML` then the Flash will get an object which may not be usable (although I haven't actually tried doing this).

Comment: What kind of trouble? Please elaborate. Also, re-examining your question, I notice that you may need to call `test_vars.htmlText` instead of just `.text`; that's assuming the DIV content you pull from the HTML page is, in fact, HTML. Also be warned that the `TextField` class can't display all HTML markup.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is as Allan describes, write a Javascript function to sit on the page and return the required value to you.

Of course, if you **can't** edit the page content, only the flash, then you do need to pass the function itself, which will actually have to be forced into the page though [JavaScript injection](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/745/4/JavaScript-and-VBScript-Injection-in-ActionScript-3/Page4.html). An example for your case, which I have not tested:

```
//prepare the JavaSctipt as an XML object for Dom insertion
var injectCode:XML = 
    <script>
        <![CDATA[
            function() {
                getElementContent = function(elementID) {
                    return document.getElementById(elementID).innerHTML;
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </script>;

//inject code
ExternalInterface.call(injectCode);
//get contents of 'divA'
var divAContent:String = ExternalInterface.call('getElementContent','divA') as String;
//get contents of 'spanB'
var spanBContent:String = ExternalInterface.call('getElementContent','spanB') as String;
```